# How do i populate list of values to a Checkcombobox (ControlsFX) from database

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to populate list of foreign key values to a Checkcombobox from my database since last night i have not made any progress. i am using ControlsFX 8.40.15
this is what i have been doing:

```
@FXML
private CheckComboBox<String> privilages;

final ObservableList<String> privList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 @FXML
private void loadPrivilages(MouseEvent event) {

    try {
        String quy = "SELECT `idPermission` FROM `Permission`";
        setPs(datahandler.prepareStatement(quy));
        setRs(getPs().executeQuery());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StaffController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        while (getRs().next()) {
            privilages.getItems().addAll(getRs().getString("idPermission"));
        }

    ObservableList privListing = privilages.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems();
        //privilages.setItems(privList);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StaffController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `setPs`, `setRs` and `getRs` methods?

Comment: What is going on here u guys want to tell me no one can help me with this

Comment: Did you debug your query? While iterating the results, were you able to print every id to `System.out`?